# mysql query with multiple conditions or orders, then save each result with diffrent variable

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to query with multiple conditions or orders then save each results to a variable?

let's say

```
SELECT * FROM table (WHERE common='yes') AS common_result (ORDER BY last_update DESC) AS update_result, (ORDER BY priority DESC) AS priority_result
```

to elaborate this:

I wanted to save the query where common='yes', then save it to common_result.

I wanted to save the query ORDER BY last_update DESC, then save it to update_result.

I wanted to save the query ORDER BY priority DESC, then save it to priority_result.

please take note that it is different to this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE common='yes'  ORDER BY last_update DESC, priority DESC
```

each condition/order are not related with each other.

is there any mysql syntax that can do this?

I use to do it this way because I think it helps to make the query lightly

Comment: what result you expect to get?

Comment: maybe if you can add sample data with desired result, we can easily understand what you really want to do.

Comment: @AkamOmer I am expecting list of rows.
JW. i'll try to provide sample data

Comment: lets separate one addition thing: the query for order by last_update and priority is (select * from table) or (select * from table where common = 'yes')

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question but I would rather do this

```
 SELECT * FROM table 
 WHERE common='yes'
 ORDER BY last_update DESC,      
 priority DESC
```

Comment: that's no solution to the posted question. She asked for posting ONE query and getting THREE different resultsets.

Comment: Obl is right. that's what I mean. I updated my question @Saju